# Directive rendering an HTML output which contains rendered HTML in an attribute value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to render an HTML like follows:

```
<div class="aClass" ng-controller="aCertainCtrl">
    <span class="aSubclass" certain-attribute="<ul class='menu'><li class='selected'><a href='/'>Home</a></li><li><a href='/about'>About</a></li></ul>">
</span>
```

How is it possible to combine two directives (from my understanding it should be done using two), one for the element itself and the other to be compiled once the first has already been compiled, giving as an output an HTML markup embedded into the `certain-atribute` value?

Of course the aim of achieving this is allowing to render a certain HTML based on some model array, say the items of a menu, templating those items on how they will look like in terms of HTML, and embedding the ouput into the `certain-attribute` value.

I'm kind of newbie in AngularJS, so that still not controlling well the whole Directives process and its possibilities.

**I know this is not the way to go**, but I would like to see how to implement such a crappy thing in angular :D

Thanks in advance.

**EDITING: Rewriting a bit for those ones who didn't understand well the issue**

1. My goal is to have some HTML markup as a value inside an inline attribute of a certain element (even though is crap and nasty). Say `<span data-some-markup="<p>Hello</p>"></span>`.
2. I would like to use an attribute directive like this: 
   `<div ng-controller="somecontroller"><my-custom-element></my-custom-element></div>`
3. `<my-custom-element>` directive rendition will depend on `someController` `$scope.data = [{name: Home, path: '/'}, { name: 'About', path: '/about' }];`
4. The desired output will be something like: 
   `<div class="aClass" ng-controller="aCertainCtrl">
       <span class="aSubclass" certain-attribute="<ul class='menu'><li class='selected'><a href='/'>Home</a></li><li><a href='/about'>About</a></li></ul>">
   </span>
   </div>`

Question is, how can you do this entirely with AngularJS?

Comment: What do you mean by "combine two directives"? What two directives?

Comment: It doesn't need, actually, to combine two directives. I don't know how many directives we would need. It was just what I was thinking, maybe we need 2 directives combined. 

So the question is, how can I achieve that HTML markup implementing my own directive/s in AngularJS? Thanks for replying, by the way.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to set `certain-attribute` to some html (as a string) and have it be compiled by the directive?

Comment: certain-attribute="<some html generated by the rendition of an angular directive>"

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. What does it mean "generated by rendition of a directive"? Can you edit and rephrase your question (not in comments) into parts: 1) this is my high level goal, 2) here's a not-yet-built directive, 3) this is the input, 4) this is the desired output, 5) this is what I tried and failed

Comment: The whole HTML that needs to be compiled as attribute of another directive approach is wrong. Stop doing it. Read about the "transclude" feature of directives.

Comment: Agreed. The concept is wrong. That's not the way to go. In addition, I solved my issues just by switching the concept I was using, since HTML markup must not be contained within an inline attribute. However, I would like to know if this is achievable with AngularJS somehow.